# Google Maps marker alignment issues during zooming when using a svg marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg

For some reason, when zooming in and out with a svg marker that's defined using a path, the marker isn't aligned correctly to it's position. This is evident in [one of google's examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom).

Interestingly, if we use one of the [built in svg symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-predefined), this does not appear to be a problem.

I am using this svg path as my marker and it also suffers from the alignment issues:

```
M 256,480c-84.828,0-153.6-68.157-153.6-152.228c0-84.081, 153.6-359.782, 153.6-359.782s 153.6,275.702, 153.6,359.782C 409.6,411.843, 340.828,480, 256,480z M 255.498,282.245c-26.184,0-47.401,21.043-47.401,46.981c0,25.958, 21.217,46.991, 47.401,46.991c 26.204,0, 47.421-21.033, 47.421-46.991 C 302.92,303.288, 281.702,282.245, 255.498,282.245z
```

What is the cause of this problem?

---

**Edit:** Thanks to MrUpsidown for solving the problem. The SVG needs to have its anchor point at (0,0) of the canvas.

See this image (I am using illustrator, but any other svg editing app should do):
[image]

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tf83z/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the anchor point of your SVG marker.

See the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon

*anchor: The position at which to anchor an image in correspondance to the location of the marker on the map. By default, the anchor is located along the center point of the bottom of the image.*

It can be tricky to find the right point but it usually is among the values of your path when using a symetric symbol and if you want to anchor it on a path edge.

```
var icon = {

    path: "M 256,480c-84.828,0-153.6-68.157-153.6-152.228c0-84.081, 153.6-359.782, 153.6-359.782s 153.6,275.702, 153.6,359.782C 409.6,411.843, 340.828,480, 256,480z M 255.498,282.245c-26.184,0-47.401,21.043-47.401,46.981c0,25.958, 21.217,46.991, 47.401,46.991c 26.204,0, 47.421-21.033, 47.421-46.991 C 302.92,303.288, 281.702,282.245, 255.498,282.245z",
    fillColor: '#FFFF00',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(255.498,-26.204),
    strokeWeight: 0,
    scale: .25,
    rotation: 180
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/Q9J9d/)</kbd>

I have added the default marker for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A few more questions: 1. How do you find the anchor point? Is there some tool? 2. I rotated the path in illustrator so that its facing the right way and we do not need to set `rotation`: `M721,216c84.8,0,153.6,68.2,153.6,152.2C874.6,452.3,721,728,721,728S567.4,452.3,567.4,368.2 C567.4,284.1,636.2,216,721,216z M721.5,413.7c26.2,0,47.4-21,47.4-47c0-26-21.2-47-47.4-47c-26.2,0-47.4,21-47.4,47 C674.1,392.7,695.3,413.7,721.5,413.7z` If by default the anchor is the bottom center point, why does the problem still exist in the rotated image?

Comment: Your new path doesn't seem to be working for me. Can you fork my fiddle and post the link here? I don't know if there is a tool to find the anchor point. I usually start at 0,0 then I try to center it like I want. Maybe there is a technique for that but I don't know it.

Comment: Not sure why happened when I posted the path in, but here's the forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N63jN/

Comment: You didn't set an anchor point. So what exactly is your question now? And is your SVG centered on its canvas?

Comment: The docs says that by default the anchor point is the bottom center of the image. If that is the case and the image is correctly rotated, why is an anchor point required to get it to align properly?

Comment: That was it! The "anchor" of the image needs to be a (0,0).